# exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location in a loop

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have a memory allocation problem. But I don't know where the problem is

The error comes up while running the loop below at 55th iteration. Below that, the code gives me what I want.

The code segment where the error happens (whole code is too long):

```
  while(k<75){  

      domainz1.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xz1,e1,row);
      domainz2.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xz2,e2,row);
      domainz3.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xz3,e3,row);
      domainz4.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xz4,e4,row);
      domainz5.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xz5,e5,row);
      domainz6.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xz6,e6,row);


      domaine1.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae1,be1,e1,ydimDom);
      domaine2.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae2,be2,e1,1);
      domaine2.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae2,be2,e2,ydimDom);
      domaine3.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae3,be3,e2,1);
      domaine3.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae3,be3,e3,ydimDom);
      domaine4.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae4,be4,e3,1);
      domaine4.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae4,be4,e4,ydimDom);
      domaine5.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae5,be5,e4,1);
      domaine5.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae5,be5,e5,ydimDom);
      domaine6.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae6,be6,e5,1);
      domaine6.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae6,be6,e6,ydimDom);
      domaine7.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Ae7,be7,e6,1);

      gmressolver2d(Ae1,xe1,be1,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Ae2,xe2,be2,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Ae3,xe3,be3,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Ae4,xe4,be4,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Ae5,xe5,be5,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Ae6,xe6,be6,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Ae7,xe7,be7,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);

      //*******************************************************************
      domaine1.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xe1,z1,row);
      domaine2.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xe2,z2,row);
      domaine3.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xe3,z3,row);
      domaine4.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xe4,z4,row);
      domaine5.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xe5,z5,row);
      domaine6.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xe6,z6,row);
      domaine7.getVerticalBoundaryBegin(xe7,z7,row);


      domainz1.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az1,bz1,z1,1);
      domainz1.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az1,bz1,z2,ydimDom);
      domainz2.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az2,bz2,z2,1);
      domainz2.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az2,bz2,z3,ydimDom);
      domainz3.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az3,bz3,z3,1);
      domainz3.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az3,bz3,z4,ydimDom);
      domainz4.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az4,bz4,z4,1);
      domainz4.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az4,bz4,z5,ydimDom);
      domainz5.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az5,bz5,z5,1);
      domainz5.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az5,bz5,z6,ydimDom);
      domainz6.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az6,bz6,z6,1);
      domainz6.drichletFunctionalUpdateVertical(Az6,bz6,z7,ydimDom);

      gmressolver2d(Az1,xz1,bz1,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Az2,xz2,bz2,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Az3,xz3,bz3,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Az4,xz4,bz4,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Az5,xz5,bz5,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);
      gmressolver2d(Az6,xz6,bz6,KrylovDim,xdim,ydimDom,COP,twoDimStencil,0,1);


      k++;

      printf("%d iterations done\n",k);
  }
```

Here almost all the terms in the brackets are arrays.

Ae1,Ae2,Az1,Az2,..... are 2D arrays 71x11

xe1,xz1,bz1,be1,e1,e2,z1,z2,......... are 1D arrays of size (71x11).

These class operators are transferring data between these arrays basically. this is a scientific code, gmressolver2d solves new problems in every iteration.

the point is my memory allocation always inceares and increases and I don't know what to do to prevent this.

Best regards,
Emre.

edit: my array allocations.

```
template <typename T> 
T ****AllocateDynamic4DArray( int nRows, int nCols, int nSlice, int kSlice)
{
      T ****dynamicArray;

      dynamicArray = new T***[nRows];
      for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
        dynamicArray[i] = new T**[nCols];
        for ( int j=0; j<nCols;j++){
            dynamicArray[i][j] = new T*[nSlice];
            for (int k=0; k<nSlice; k++){
                dynamicArray[i][j][k] = new T[kSlice];
                for(int l=0;l<kSlice;l++){
                    dynamicArray[i][j][k][l] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
      }
      return dynamicArray;
}
template <typename T>
T ***AllocateDynamic3DArray(int nRows, int nCols, int nSlice){
      T ***dynamicArray;

      dynamicArray = new T**[nRows];
      for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
        dynamicArray[i] = new T*[nCols];
        for ( int j=0; j<nCols;j++){
            dynamicArray[i][j] = new T[nSlice];
            for (int k=0; k<nSlice; k++){
                    dynamicArray[i][j][k]= 0;
                }
            }
        }
      return dynamicArray;
}
template <typename T>
T **AllocateDynamic2DArray(int nRows, int nCols){
      T **dynamicArray;

      dynamicArray = new T*[nRows];
      for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
        dynamicArray[i] = new T[nCols];
        for ( int j=0; j<nCols;j++){
                dynamicArray[i][j]= 0;
            }
        }
      return dynamicArray;
}
template <typename T>
T *AllocateDynamicVector(int nRows){
      T *dynamicArray;

      dynamicArray = new T[nRows];
      for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
            dynamicArray[i]= 0;
        }
      return dynamicArray;
}
```

Comment: There is no memory being allocated in the loop. The problem is in one of the functions that get executed during the loop. Please show the definitions of these functions.

Comment: This is very hard to answer. Your problem is basically that you run out of memory, but we have no idea where memory is allocated since any of your functions might do it. Can you make a working example?

Comment: How much RAM is in your system?  Typically that exception is thrown by `new` when you run out of memory.  Also for each loop, typically how much memory is allocated? When you repeat the loop, do you need every generated item on the heap to remain in memory from the previous loop iteration?

Comment: @Jason: I've got 4GB of RAM. I tried to increase the heap size but my ram allocation rises up to 100% anyways. No, I don't need every generated item, I can delete e1....e6 & z1....z6 if necessary. maybe I should allocate and delete them in the while-loop? would it help?

Comment: @Oswald @honk: The functions just take dynamic arrays and transfer the information in between. No new array is initialized in these functions.

Comment: @Emre: There's something very weird going on if memory use keeps increasing drastically, yet you don't dynamically allocate anything.

Comment: @Emre: If you want, you can paste all relevant portions of code somewhere like http://pastebin.com and we can take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the program in your debugger, and set the debugger so that it breaks when an exception is thrown. Once the program is halted (because of the exception), use the call stack feature of your debugger to see in which context your exception is thrown.

I'd like to give you more detailed instructions, but you don't specify what platform/compiler you're using.

---

This [how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) describes how to set up Visual Studio to break upon any exception.

This [how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx) describes how to use the call stack.

Comment: thank you emile, now I know where the problem is. I'm still a bit confused. This is another question - but can't you delete a multidimensional array "A" as "delete[] A", or do you have to set a loop for that?

Comment: @Emre: It depends. Is it an array of arrays? Or is it a flat 1D array, where you compute a 1D index out of a pair of 2D indices? Just show us how you allocate those 2D arrays, and we'll know which.

Comment: @Emre: Yes, you have to delete[] all nested arrays in a loop.

Comment: I was only writing "delete[] A", regardless whether it's a 4D or 1D array.. thank you emile.

Answer (score 1):

Use [UMDH.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343) to take snapshots of the app's heap usage before successive loops, then compare the two snapshots.  If properly set up, the callstacks of all alloactions in the interim will be seen.

Answer (score 1):

When deleting the arrays in the manner you're allocating them, a single call to `delete [] array_name` won't work because each index in a dimension of the array is a newly allocated "sub-array" of pointers.  So you're going to have to loop through each of the row/columns/slice/etc. of the array and call `delete []` on the array of pointers that make up the indicies of the array.  For instance, to deallocate one of your 3D-arrays, you'll have to-do something like the following:

```
for (int i=0; i < column_size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j < slice_size; j++)
    {
        delete [] array_name[i][j];
    }

    delete [] array_name[i];
}

delete [] array_name;
```